# Regular expression to change string between curly brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have a file and I want to change text inside it with regex.

```
"code": {
  "restore": 1,
  "restore_on_startup": true,
},
```

I want to change the text between

`"code": {`

and

`},`

I tried something like

`Regex.Replace(subject, @"?xxx.*?yyy", "Replace");`

But as my text contains new lines, it didn't work.

Comment: A regex is the wrong tool. Use a JSON parser.

Comment: Could you please guide me for Json parser? A Json parser and a sample tutorial about my question would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for your seample, it will replace everything inside the brackets

```
Regex.Replace(subject,"(?<=\"code\":\\s{).*?(?=},)", "replace", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

**"code": {
  "restore": 1,
  "restore_on_startup": true,
},**

will yield

**"code": {replace},**

The regex is basically saying match everything that is prefixed with `"code": {` and is suffixed with `},` then replace everything inside with my *replace*.  You may need to tweak it to suit your needs.

Comment: It is working. Thanks for helping. May I ask what RegexOptions.Singleline does? Why not MultiLine?

Comment: @digiogi Multiline is for when you want `^` and `$` to match each line and Singleline makes `.` match everything, including line breaks, see this link for more info, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx

Comment: I understood it very clearly. And what `\\s` does? I don't understand regex clearly and want to learn it.

Comment: @digiogi `\s` stands for blank space, you can use a blank space [ ], but imho **\s** makes it stand out, and clearer especially if you want to match multiple spaces e.g. `a   b` (with 3 spaces between a and b) you can represent as **a\s{3}b**. I suggest you check out google or bing to truly understand the power of regex, I was initially taught to avoid it, but learned to love it for its power :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers Jason. I'm glad to see stackoverflow has you.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
(.|\\r|\\n)*?
```

instead of

```
.*?
```

or use the multiline property in the RegexOptions class

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you go line by line searching for `"code": {`.

That found, from the same line start looking for `}`. (Beware to look after the `code` part in the first line, because there may be a `}` before the `code`)

Go storing all lines with a `List<string> Add` until you find the `}`.

After that, concat all lines you found in a single string, do the replacement. 
Remove all those lines from file and add the new formed string.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try this if I can't make it with Json parser.